# How can My Asp.Net C# class return a json format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

How would like a class that will return a json format.

This method work Great in the controller
but when I want to put in a Class, the Json object don't seem to exist.

```
 public JsonResult Test()
 {
      //Error   1   The name 'Json' does not exist in the current context   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mvcinfosite\mvcinfosite\Validation\ValidationClass\BaseValidator.cs  66  20  mvcinfosite
      return Json(new { errMsg = "test" });
 }
```

I want to put that code in a simple class. I want be able to call this method in many controllers.

Thanks.

**EDIT** 
This is my Class **(Where the code dosen't work)**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using mvcinfosite.Models;
using mvcinfosite.Base;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class BaseValidator
{
     public JsonResult Test()
     {
         return Json(new { errMsg = "test" });
     }
}
```

Comment: do you have the proper `using` statement in your class?

Comment: It is usually easier to understand what's going on if you post a **not working** code instead the one which works fine.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`Json()` is a method on the base controller which returns a JsonResult. You need to do the serialization yourself.

```
return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new { errMsg = "test" });
```

You will need to include `using System.Web.Script.Serialization`.

Comment: Thx Ryan , I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Jean-Francois You said you need to do this in many controllers don't you need an ActionResult instead of a String? Just a clarification.

Comment: I see what he's asking now. Yeah it would be better to just return a JsonResult, but I'm not 100% sure about how validators work in MVC as I haven't used them before.

Answer (score 30):

`return Json(new { errMsg = "test"});`

is a convenience method on Controller that is equivalent to

```
return new JsonResult(){
      Data = new { errMsg = "test"},
      JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet
};
```

Comment: Thx jbtule, your solution work great too... I Can only put one as an answer. But yours work perfecly. Thx again :)

Comment: @Jean-Francois it's fine, it's just that both answer return very different results, @Ryan's answer returns a string, which is not ideal if you are just going to return it as the result of an action method, but more idea if you need to do something not related to the MVC pattern.

Comment: This should be the answer as NewtonSoft JSON is used widely in .NET

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked (mind the change of the return type to Object):

```
public Object Test()
{
      return new { errMsg = "test" };
}
```