# How to create a JSON WebService in c# ASP.Net with a valid JSON output and query with JQuery/Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json, web-services

I´ve created a **c# ASP.Net JSON WebService**. But I have big troubles with reading the data from this WebService because in my eyes the output is not a valid JSON format?

Normally you should get a [object, object] back as data. But I get [object, document]
What I am doing wrong or what I am missing?

**My current output looks like the following:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">{
  "Email": "james@example.com",
  "Active": true,
  "CreatedDate": "2013-01-20T00:00:00Z",
  "Roles": [
    "User",
    "Admin"
  ]
}</string>
```

**This is my JQuery-Ajax call:**

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   //dataType: "json", <-- When I uncomment this line the request fails :(
   url: "http://webservices.domain.local/service.asmx/getData?name=",

   success: function(data){
      console.log(data); // Output is: [object Document] instead of [object, object]
   },
   error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){

   }
});
```

**This is the code from my WebService:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace DataWebService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Service1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class SPServices : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public string getData(string name)
        {
            Account account = new Account
            {
                Email = "james@example.com",
                Active = true,
                CreatedDate = new DateTime(2013, 1, 20, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
                Roles = new List<string>
                  {
                    "User",
                    "Admin"
                  }
            };
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(account, Formatting.Indented);
        }
    }

    public class Account
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public IList<string> Roles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**The WebConfig File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
      <!--<sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
          <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
          <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
            <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
            <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
            <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
          </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
      </sectionGroup>-->
    </configSections>  
    <appSettings/>
    <connectionStrings/>
    <system.web>
      <webServices>
        <protocols>
          <add name="HttpGet"/>
          <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
      </webServices>
        <compilation debug="true" >
          <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
          </assemblies>
        </compilation>
    <!--
      The <authentication> section enables configuration 
      of the security authentication mode used by 
      ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
    -->
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <!--
       The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
       of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
       during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
       it enables developers to configure html error pages 
       to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

       <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
         <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
         <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
       </customErrors>
    -->
      <pages>
        <controls>
          <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
          <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </controls>
      </pages>

      <httpHandlers>
        <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <!--<add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>-->
      </httpHandlers>
      <httpModules>
        <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </httpModules>
    </system.web>
    <system.codedom>
      <compilers>
        <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4"
                  type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
          <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
        </compiler>
      </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
    <!-- 
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->
    <system.webServer>
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
      <modules>
        <remove name="ScriptModule" />
        <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </modules>
      <handlers>
        <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
        <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory" />
        <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" />
        <remove name="ScriptResource" />
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode"
             type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode"
             type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </handlers>
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
    <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding appliesTo="v2.0.50727" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I would be really happy if someone could help me... I spent the whole weekend into this but I couldn´t find a solution for this... :-(

Comment: You create XML instead of JSON and ajax by default if the content is xml it create xml document.

Comment: Why do I create XML insted of JSON? In my WebService I defined that the return value should be JSON and I also tried to use a JSON Library... Any idea how I can change the output to JSON?

Comment: Looks like this has been answered before:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300855/how-can-my-asp-net-c-sharp-class-return-a-json-format

Comment: @JoeBrunscheon I think not, also if I try to use: `return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new { errMsg = "test" });` I still get back the wrong format... Any more ideas?

Answer (score 8):

Add the following using:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
```

And change your methode  to :

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public JsonResult getData(string name)
        {
            Account account = new Account
            {
                Email = "james@example.com",
                Active = true,
                CreatedDate = new DateTime(2013, 1, 20, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
                Roles = new List<string>
                  {
                    "User",
                    "Admin"
                  }
            };
            return Json(account);
        }
```

i think it will work like this

Answer (score 1):

Try using the ASP.net web-api (part of MVC 4) instead as your core project. when a controller-action returns an object it will automatically be serialized to xml or json depending on the request. That is your browser demands either one and the service provides.

They've even ripped out the old MS-library for JSON and replaced it with the newtonsoft one. This means that some scenarios are supported by json serialization and not xml serialization. If you need those features, you can remove the default xml-serializer and only support json.

Good luck! :)

Comment: mh... I think I do not really understand what do you mean... maybe you could describe it with a little bit more details so that I get the right direction? (or maybe some links?)

Comment: I mean primarily http://www.asp.net/web-api, which is the first hit on google for asp.net web-api. It should tell you everything you need to know. Mainly I'm thinking you're complicating things for yourself by picking an old more general technology over a newer more streamlined one. So I point you in the direction of a technology which should make life easier for you. However I'm not going to do the whole job for you. :)

Comment: The thing about newtonsoft is an aside that I mentioned since you have included it in your webservice. I've been down that road and it's messy. Try a newer tech. ;)