# Change the format of the Data into JSON

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json

I want to change my data into desired *JSON* format. My data looks like this:

```
[
  "{
     id:001,
     name:akhilesh,
   }",
  "{
     id:002,
     name:Ram,
   }"
]
```

I want to convert the above data to valid *JSON*:

```
[
   {
     "id":"001",
     "name":"akhilesh"
   },
   {
     "id":"002",
     "name":"Ram"
   }
]
```

I tried the following, but none of these helped:

1. `JSON.serialize`
2. `JSON.parse`
3. `eval`

I need help for this.

The exact data response from server side is:

```
{
    "d": [
        "{id:413,title:ranjan,start:413,end:413}",
        "{id:414,title:raja,start:414,end:414}",
        "{id:415,title:raja g,start:415,end:415}",
        "{id:416,title:abhh,start:416,end:416}",
        "{id:417,title:chta,start:417,end:417}",
        "{id:418,title:Raju,start:418,end:418}",
        "{id:419,title:Ranjan,start:419,end:419}",
        "{id:420,title:Raja,start:420,end:420}",
        "{id:421,title:chitti,start:421,end:421}",
        "{id:422,title:Raja,start:422,end:422}",
        "{id:423,title:raja,start:423,end:423}",
        "{id:424,title:yash,start:424,end:424}",
        "{id:425,title:vsg,start:425,end:425}",
        "{id:431,title:Vimal11,start:431,end:431}",
        "{id:432,title:Aruhi,start:432,end:432}",
        "{id:434,title:Aruhi,start:434,end:434}",
        "{id:435,title:,start:435,end:435}",
        "{id:436,title:xs,start:436,end:436}",
        "{id:437,title:rajkj,start:437,end:437}",
        "{id:438,title:mmt,start:438,end:438}",
        "{id:439,title:xaxa,start:439,end:439}",
        "{id:440,title:yash,start:440,end:440}"
    ]
}
```

**Server Side Code**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<string> getData()
{
    List<string> data = new List<string>();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ACME-PC\\SQL;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=ClinicApplication"))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DISTINCT Patient_ID,First_Name,fromtime,totime,Date from tbl_AddPatientInfo", con);
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {

                string id = "{" +
                    "\"id:\"" + dr["Patient_ID"].ToString() + "," +
                    "title:" + dr["First_Name"].ToString() + "," +
                    "start:" + dr["Patient_ID"].ToString() + "," +
                    "end:" + dr["Patient_ID"].ToString() +
                    "}";
                string ids = id.Replace(@"""", "");

                data.Add(ids);
            }
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why can't you return proper json from server itself ?

Comment: Because i used list to return this , In list the data itself coming dynamically itself

Comment: There is only one proper way to solve problems of incorrect data formats - stop using them. It is like "my web-server returns text in French and with many typos; I want it to be displayed in proper English".

Comment: Change `},]` to `}]` and `,}` to `}`. The extra commas suggests another item in the arrays. . For example, you want to keep the comma between `}{`.

Comment: @AkhileshSingh Please add the data exactly as you're getting in the response, no need of formatting it here as it'll invalidate the string.

Comment: @AkhileshSingh are you talking about `List` in java ?

Comment: List in C sharp @Susheel Singh

Comment: Fix the server side code to emit **valid** JSON. Do not attempt to fix broken JSON in JavaScript.

Comment: @Tushar i update the Code please lets a look.

Comment: @AkhileshSingh Can you change the server side API to return JSON encoded data?

Comment: i tried sir but its not changing , so i thought i can change it to client side, It is possible or not sir.

Comment: @AkhileshSingh You should change the server to return valid JSON, now the data is not consistent. `title` contains space for 415 and it is not present for 435, if changing data format to JSON is not possible, at least make the data consistent

Comment: please post your `c#` code lets see if we can help you better

Comment: @AkhileshSingh See [How to return JSon object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441880/how-to-return-json-object) and [How can My Asp.Net C# class return a json format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300855/how-can-my-asp-net-c-sharp-class-return-a-json-format). Try `return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new data);` after including `using System.Web.Script.Serialization`

Comment: @Tushar i already go through to this link but its not working in my case, I tried again. After that i say to you sir and thanx for you precious time Sir.

Comment: If that server is under control of your country, then you need to tell your manager that the server team is producing broken JSON. It's quite clear that they _intend_ to produce JSON but are just failing miserably. That's gross incompetence.

Comment: @SalmanA: It's actually valid JSON (as far as I can see), just quite useless: It's an array in a dictionary, containing strings. Just the strings don't contain text, but something that seems to look a little bit like JSON. I've seen people sending strings containing _actual_ JSON (or XML, or HTML) which is enough of a pain, but this isn't.

Comment: @gnasher729 let me rephrase then: tweak the server side script to send useful JSON. Is that better?

Comment: 17 upvotes to do this guy's job for him!? Some day, you will go to a doctor's office and they will be running the code that this guy is asking for on Stack Overflow. Don't be an enabler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of doing a complex `regex`(which is might not work in some conditions) by using `javascript`. Its better to do server side changes to get `JSON` data correctly.

> Avoid building the JSON by string concatenation, since you risk sending broken data when the string contains certain special characters in JSON. This should be done with JSON serializer.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string getData(){
   List<Dictionary<string, string>> data = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
   Dictionary<string, string> item;
   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ACME-PC\\SQL;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=ClinicApplication"))
   {
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DISTINCT Patient_ID,First_Name,fromtime,totime,Date from tbl_AddPatientInfo", con);
       {
           con.Open();
           SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

           while (dr.Read())
           {
                item = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                item.Add("id", dr["Patient_ID"]+"");
                item.Add("title", dr["First_Name"]+"");
                item.Add("start", dr["Patient_ID"]+"");
                item.Add("end", dr["Patient_ID"]+"");
                data.Add(item);
           }
           return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(data);
       }
    }
}
```

**modification to your existing code:**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<string> getData(){
    List<string> data = new List<string>();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ACME-PC\\SQL;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=ClinicApplication"))
    {
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DISTINCT Patient_ID,First_Name,fromtime,totime,Date from tbl_AddPatientInfo", con);
       {
           con.Open();
           SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

           while (dr.Read())
           {
                string id = "{" +
                   "\"id\":"  + "\""+dr["Patient_ID"].ToString()+"\"" + "," +
                   "\"title\":" + "\""+dr["First_Name"].ToString()"\"" + "," +
                   "\"start\":" + "\""+dr["Patient_ID"].ToString()"\"" + "," +
                   "\"end\":" + "\""+dr["Patient_ID"].ToString() + "\""+
                   "}";
                data.Add(id);
           }
           return data;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: just made a small change check again

Comment: are you getting correct response now. If not please post the updated output, I will help you further

Comment: Avoid building the JSON by string concatenation, since you risk sending broken data when the string contains certain special characters in JSON. This should be done with JSON serializer.

Answer (score 13):

If you've control on how the response is sent from the server, I'd recommend to use `json_encode(response);` if using PHP or `JSON.stringify(response)` if using Javascript(node.js) or similar method for other languages. And then on client-side, you can use `JSON.parse(response)` directly on the response to get JSON object.

The elements of array need to be wrapped in quotes, so that it can be converted to JSON using `JSON.parse`. Then `map` can be used with JSON.parse.

```js
var arr = [
    '{"id":"001","name":"akhilesh"}',
    '{"id":"002","name":"Ram"}'
];

arr = arr.map(JSON.parse);

console.log(arr);
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr, 0, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

---

If you don't have quotes in the string, you can use regex to add them and make it suitable to pass to `JSON.parse`.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/697r3cyr/)

```js
var arr = [
    "{id:001,name:akhilesh}",
    "{id:002,name:Ram}"
];

arr = arr.map(function(e) {
    // Add quotes on every alphanumeric character
    return JSON.parse(e.replace(/(\w+)/g, '"$1"'));
});

console.log(arr);
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr, 0, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: did you read his question clearly ? he doesn't have double quotes in before and wants double quotes in after.

Comment: My data is coming dynamically it should work for this??

Comment: @SusheelSingh That's not **valid string**, that's formatted when added in question, there will be no spaces when the response is sent from the server

Comment: hope so, let the OP reply with exact data

Comment: yes, but I don't feel good tinkering code on client side. I think it would be better if he can return json properly. so your answer is correct now. upvote

Comment: @SusheelSingh I feel the same way, you can read my comments on answer and start of my answer :)

Comment: @Tushar Just a small note, PHP is `json_encode`, with an `_`, not a `.` :)

Answer (score 4):

Fixing JSON via JavaScript is wrong. Using string functions to generate JSON on server side is equally rubbish. Your code will break for example when the data contains `"`, new lines and what not.

I would rather use some library that generates JSON. Here is a complete example that uses [`JavaScriptSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx). It can convert various objects. Here we use a `List` of `Dictionary` objects:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

[WebService]
[ScriptService]

public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string getData()
    {
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> data = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ACME-PC\\SQL;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=ClinicApplication"))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DISTINCT Patient_ID,First_Name,fromtime,totime,Date from tbl_AddPatientInfo", con);
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    Dictionary<string, object> item = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    item.Add("id", dr["Patient_ID"]);
                    item.Add("title", dr["First_Name"]);
                    item.Add("start", dr["Patient_ID"]);
                    item.Add("end", dr["Patient_ID"]);
                    data.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(data);
    }
}
```

Testing with jQuery:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/testing/WebService1.asmx/getData",
    method: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (json) {
        var data = jQuery.parseJSON(json.d);
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Console Log:

```
[{
    "id": 413,
    "title": "ranjan",
    "start": 413,
    "end": 413
}, {
    "id": 414,
    "title": "raja",
    "start": 414,
    "end": 414
}]
```

Comment: Sir you assign the value statically but my data is coming from database and then add to the list. How it can be done?

Comment: It is just for illustration. See Susheel's revised answer who borrowed code from my example to create complete example using data reader.