# C# MVC returning bool to json

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem, i got strange behaviour if returning data from Action method to json using Return Json()

this code always give me alert "success"

```
//In action method in controller
//either
    return Json(true);
//or
    return Json(false);

//In view    
    success: function (data) {
        if (data) {
            alert("success");
        } else {
            alert("failed");
        }
    }
```

this code always give me alert "failed"

```
//In action method in controller
//either
    return Json(new { success = true });
//or
    return Json(new { success = false });


    success: function (data) {
        if (data.success) {
            alert("success");
        } else {
            alert("failed");
        }
    }
```

this code always give me alert "failed"

```
//In action method in controller
//either    
    return Json(new { success = "true" });
//or
    return Json(new { success = "false" });

    success: function (data) {
        if (data.success == "true") {
            alert("success");
        } else {
            alert("failed");
        }
    }
```

I'm using visual studio 2015, need your explanation sir. thank you

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300855/how-can-my-asp-net-c-sharp-class-return-a-json-format)? Json() is a method on the base controller which returns a JsonResult. You need to do the serialization yourself.

Comment: @ramblin how that related to this question?

Comment: you can add console.log(data) in your success function and see for yourself what value is being returned from your action method

Comment: Not able to duplicate any of this behavior

Comment: @RamblinRose In that question the OP called `Json()` from a class not inheriting from `Controller` which is why it did not exist and they had to do the serialization themselves. Otherwise `Json()` does perform serialization.

Comment: Are you sure you don't also have an `error:` handler that also shows `alert("failed");`?

Comment: Before, i use dataType: 'html' and data.success is undefined. Then i delete the dataType it returning the right. And dataType: 'JSON' gives me the same result with without dataType. Can anyone gives me reference link about dataType in ajax?

Comment: [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) - Your returning json, so it must be `dataType: 'json'` (or omit the options and the ajax method will work it out)