# Json is returning "new {success = true } " as String on a blank page when FormData is used in ajax method

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I am trying to get data and images from popup modal via ajax method, I am using formdata to put data and images and send it to my  action(which returns JsonResult). 
Data is sent to action and I can save it to database but Json does not redirects to view, instead it returns "{success = true}" as a String on a blank page.

I understand that the problem is formdata as data, I tried to send only data  (data: $(this).serialize()), without images and it got right(redirected me to my view). Yet I don't understand what is wrong i case of formdata, I have been seaching solution for 2 days but can't find proper answer

```
    //model class

    public class ArticlesCustomClass
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }


        [Required]
        [AllowHtml]
        [Display(Name = "Content")]
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public HttpPostedFileBase[] Images { get; set; }
    }
```

```
        //action 
         [HttpPost]
         [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public JsonResult CreateArticles(ArticlesCustomClass model)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var filesList = new List<HttpPostedFileBase>();
                for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
                {
                    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[i];
                    filesList.Add(file);
                }
                ArticlesData.CreateArticles(model,filesList.ToArray());
                return Json(new {success = true });

            }
            return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

```
//View
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateArticles", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control long-textbox required" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Content, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Content, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control long-textbox ckeditor required", @rows = 10 })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Content, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="uploader" class="form-group">
            <div class="control-label col-md-2">Add images</div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div><input type="file" id="UploadFile" class="btn btn-primary" name="Images" multiple></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

```
    //ajax method
    function bindForm(dialog) {

   var formdata = new FormData($('form', dialog)).get(0); 

    $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
        $('#progress').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: formdata,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                    $('#progress').hide();
                    location.reload();
                } else {
                    $('#progress').hide();
                    $('#myModalContent').html(result);
                    bindForm();
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
       });
     }
```

Comment: Aside from the issue, but calling `window.reload()` after making an AJAX request makes that request almost entirely pointless

Comment: According to the url below, you should change the code which returns the JSON object with the success=true in it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300855/how-can-my-asp-net-c-sharp-class-return-a-json-format

Comment: @Dennisvdh the issue there is because the user is trying to return Json outside of a class which inherits from `Controller`. `return Json()` is fine, otherwise.

Comment: any ideas? .......

Comment: window.reload() works fine when I use data: $(this).serialize() in ajax method